# Putting referral URLs into Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a site that has referral links. It is set up so that `http://site.com/refer/abc` redirects to `http://site.com/destination`.

Whenever I enter `http://site.com/refer/abc` as the data-href for Facebook's Like button, though, it just rewrites the link as `http://site.com/destination`, which causes me to lose referral tracking.

Any way I can keep the referral link with the Facebook Like button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by checking to see whether it was a bot or human that visited `http://site.com/refer/abc`. If you're using Rails:

```
request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].match(/\(.*https?:\/\/.*\)/) ? "is robot" : "is human"
```

If it was a human, I let it redirect like normal. If it was a bot I just rendered the page with no redirect - the same one that the human would see at `http://site.com/destination`. This made Facebook keep the original referrer URL but still display the relevant meta tags for that page when someone Liked the page.

EDIT: I've found that if you want Facebook to crawl your Like button right as it's created, you need to curl Facebook's URL linter each time a new button is created:

```
curl https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json
```

This will update the Like button metadata immediately. [More info here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)